# How can I create an array out of something like $("li").text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I want to get all text of each `li` and save it into an array, how might I do that.

For example, something like ...

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

should give me an array like

```
["1", "2", "3", ..., "10"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the `<ul>` an id and something like

```
$("#yourulid li").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FAQtt/)

For more details take a look at

[**`jQuery.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and [**`.get()`**](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

If you want to get the text as a comma separated string then only you need to use [**`.join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: Now *that's* cool. I've always wanted a one-liner like that. +1 for one-liners.

Comment: If you just want the array, discard the last `.join(',')` bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use each to iterate over li list first and then put every text in an array.

```
var arr=[];

$("li").each(function(n){

arr[n] = $(this).text();

});
```

Comment: To make your answer look better, highlight your code with your mouse and press the button with a curly-bracket on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [.map() function](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
$('li').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
});
```

Edit: As pointed out by @rahul I wrapped "this" in a jQuery object.

Comment: To make use of the `.text()` method you need to wrap it in a jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [];
$("ul").children().each(function(index) {
    myArray[index] = $(this).text(); 
});
```

Comment: It's rather self-explanatory in my opinion. You loop through the children of the ul and append the text values to the array.

Comment: Just saying. You're assuming the OP is proficient in jQuery, which doesn't seem to be the case (you can slop down words, join them with function decelerations, and you've got valid jQuery code).

Answer (score 0):

The crude and inelegant way of doing it:

```
var output = [];

$('#your-ul li').each(function()
{
  output.push($(this).text());
});
```